# C# Making a program finish processes before advancing

Tags: c#, process

In C#, how do you make a program only process one thing at a time? I've been working on a patching system, and I think I have the coding all correct but  can't test it because a lot of the functions are trying to process all at once when they need to be processing in an order. The program doesn't even let the display shown up before it starts trying to process everything. Because none of them return a value other then the main function all the functions are set to void. I thought about maybe using a return value inside of a loop to make sure the program is finished with that step first before moving on but it still leaves the problem of the program not even showing up until everything is done processing which its suppose to show the progress of everything. Any suggestions of tips?

Edit: I don't know what to post in the code, so im posting all the main functions:

```
    public void DSP_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (v1 >= v2)
        {
            File_Progress_Title.Text = "100%";
            Update_Status.Text = "Divine Shadows is currently up to date.";
            Application.DoEvents();
            Process.Start("Divine Shadows.exe");
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Update_Status.Text = "Checking For Updates...";
            Application.DoEvents();

            if (!Directory.Exists(tempFilePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFilePath);
            }

            using (SqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {
                SqlCon.Open();
                string command = "SELECT * FROM version where version > '" + v1 + "' ORDER BY version LIMIT 1";
                MySqlCommand GetLatestVersion = new MySqlCommand(command, SqlCon);

                using (MySqlDataReader DR = GetLatestVersion.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(DR.Read())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            string LatestVersion = Convert.ToString(DR.GetValue(1));
                            string WebURL = Convert.ToString(DR.GetValue(2));
                            update.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(WebURL), tempFilePath + "patch" + LatestVersion + ".zip");
                            update.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(download);
                            update.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(extration);
                            Application.Restart();
                        }
                        while (v1 < v2);
                        Process.Start("Divine Shadows.exe");
                        Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void download(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (v1 >= v2)
        {
            File_Progress_Title.Text = "100%";
            Update_Status.Text = "Divine Shadows is currently up to date.";
            Application.DoEvents();
            Process.Start("Divine Shadows.exe");
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Update_Status.Text = "Downloading Updates...";
            Application.DoEvents();
            File_Progress_Display.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            File_Progress_Title.Text = Convert.ToString(e.ProgressPercentage) + "%";
        }
    }

    public void extration(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (v1 >= v2)
        {
            File_Progress_Title.Text = "100%";
            Update_Status.Text = "Divine Shadows is currently up to date.";
            Application.DoEvents();
            Process.Start("Divine Shadows.exe");
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Update_Status.Text = "Installing Updates, Please Wait...";
            Application.DoEvents();
            UnzipFile(extactFile, extractLocation);
        }
    }

    public static void UnzipFile(string extactFile, string extractLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            FastZip fastZip = new FastZip();
            fastZip.CreateEmptyDirectories = false;
            fastZip.ExtractZip(extactFile, extractLocation, FastZip.Overwrite.Always, null, null, null, false); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error unzipping file \"" + extactFile + "\"", ex);
        }
        File.Delete(extactFile);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using any parallel library method for processing?

Comment: Given that your only reference to code is that you're "using the WebClient() function" (it's a class, not a function), this is going to require psychic powers. Post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not WebClient() specific, its about how your application is working with threads.

In general, winforms applications have one GUI Thread. This thread is used to executed your methods and also updating the user interface. If you start a long term process, the gui thread gets locked till the operation is finished. Thats the reason why your display is not shown.

You can solve that problem by implementing the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). On that website you can also find an example how to implement it. Let the BackgroundWorker do your patching process and use events inside the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() method to update your GUI.

Comment: Thanks, that actually might help. I'll try that really quick and see if it works

Comment: If you need further instructions on how to implement the BackgroundWorker, pls let me know.

Comment: ok i think I understood what to do, but if you dont mind could you please look over the script and see if I did it right? http://pastebin.com/Kqby8i8t

My host is down right now so i can't exactly test the script.

Comment: Wow, that is much code :S There are several things you are doing wrong. dont use the worker.IsBusy method to dynamically set a RunWorkerCompleted method at runtime. You can do that in your constructor next to backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress. It will call the RunWorkerCompleted automatically.

2) You dont need Application.DoEvents() 

3) The code looks like you want to build a updater for some exe file. If "Divine Shadows.exe" is a .Net Application you should consider to use Microsoft ClickOnce for a much easier to integrate update solution

Comment: This is actually a patching system for an MMO i've been working on. I'm just not used to working with threading as the scripting for my game engine doesn't require it. I originally had the gateway and the patching system as one file and it worked, but if i ever had to update the patching system itself for any reason at all I couldn't as it would require me to overwrite a file that's in use.

Comment: What is clickonce exactly? If it a program, or an assembly reference? I found what it does, but nothing on what it is or how to find it

Comment: Maybe you should start a second quesion about click once if google does not inform you well enough. Basically it is a tool to create setup routines for .net applications and it also has a update functionallity integrated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c#4 or newer you can use the Task Parallel Library to perform tasks asynchronously, thus leaving your UI response while thing are being downloaded. First of all you need a reference:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

And some code:

```
public void YourMainFunction()
{
    var urls = new List<string>();
    urls.Add("http://google.com");
    urls.Add("http://yahoo.com");

    foreach(var url in urls)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<DownloadResult>(() => 
             DownloadIt(url))
             .ContinueWith(WorkDone, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}

private class DownloadResult
{
    public string Url {get; set;}
    public string Result {get; set;}
}

private DownloadResult DownloadIt(string url)
{
    var downloadResult = new DownloadResult{ Url = url };
    var client = new WebClient();
    downloadResult.Result = client.DownloadString(url);
    return downloadResult;
}

private void WorkDone(Task<DownloadResult> task)
{
    if(task.IsFaulted)
    {
        //An exception was thrown 
        MessageBox.Show(task.Exception.ToString());
        return;
    }

    //Everything went well
    var downloadResult = task.Result;
    //Here you can update your UI to reflect progress.
    MessageBox.Show(downloadResult.Result);

}
```